# How to get the value from different tables in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I am new to JPA.

I have this problem for which I could not figure out a solution.
Lets say I have 3 tables:A,B,C.

```
Columns of A,B,C:
-----------------
table-A:
--------
ID|size|foreignKey_B_Id|

table-B:
-------
ID|scale_value|foreignKey_C_Id

table-C:
--------
ID|scale|
```

table-C contains the scales of the measurements.

table-B contains the scalevalues of the measurements and a foreign key to C.ID

table-A contains the size of the measurements and a foreign key to B.ID

The annotations of the table-A:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class Scale {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="scale")
    private String scale ;

    @Column(name="foreignkey_B_Id")
    private Long fid;
}
```

A.foreignKey_B_Id is obtained through POST method.

I need to set the value of A.scale concatenating the values of C.scale and B.scale_value during the creation of new row in table-A.

How can I achieve this.

table-B and table-C are also present with all the values.And all are one to one mappings.

Comment: *And all are one to one mappings*. You're not showing any OneToOne association. You shouldn't have any `fid`field in Scale. You should have a OneToOne or ManyToOne association instead: A has a B which has a C. That said, I don't even understand what you're asking. Get the B from the database using EntiryManager.find(), then get the corresponding C, and use String concatenation. What's the problem?

Comment: you should have classes for each table and define one to one mapping on corresponding field like @onetoone